# Can you bind multiple emails to one Cognito User account using AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Basically i want to create one Cognito User account , that is connected to multiple emails. Another user shouldn't be able to create an account using one of these connected emails.
Can this be done in AWS cognito User Pools ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not available as a feature in Cognito at the moment (multiple phone/email) for users. However, we have an existing feature request for this and I will +1 the feature on your behalf.

Comment: Hi Ionut, is this feature available now? If not, you can +1 the feature request on my behalf. Thanks!

Comment: you can +1 the feature request on my behalf too

Comment: I am looking forward to seeing this solution.

Comment: Can you paste the link for feature?

Comment: This would be very useful